# Изменение значений элементов определённого класса на jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Добрый день.
Есть кнопки с определённым классом.
Мне надо при нажатии другой кнопки сделать все кнопки с данным классом видимыми/невидимыми или изменить надпись на кнопках.
Как это сделать?

Есть кнопки `<button class='btnDelStud' id=btndel5 >Х</button>`.

Есть  неработающий код:

```
$("#CanDelete").click (function() {
    //$(".btnDelStud").val("-");
        //$(".btnDelStud").attr("color", 'blue');
});
```

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Я вроде так и делал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#CanDelete").click (function() {
    $(".btnDelStud").html("-");
    $(".btnDelStud").css({"color": 'blue'});
    $(".btnDelStud").hide();
    $(".btnDelStud").show();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/css/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Огромное спасибо.